# How to export Ramda curried function in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ramda.js

I'm new to TypeScript. I have some JavaScript code written with Ramda and I want to use it in TypeScript project.

This is a generic sort function in JavaScript:

```
var charOrdAFactoryBase = R.curry(function(sortDir, prepare){
    return function(a, b) {
        a = prepare(a);
        b = prepare(b);
        if(R.isNil(a) && R.isNil(b)) return 0;
        if(R.isNil(a)) return 1;
        if(R.isNil(b)) return -1;
        if (a > b)
            return sortDir === "asc" ? 1 : -1;
        if (a < b)
            return sortDir === "asc" ? -1 : 1;
        return 0;
    };
});
```

I tried to make:

```
export function charOrdAFactoryBase;
```

But TypeScript compiler says: Function implementation is missing or not immediately following the declaration.

Is it possible to export Ramda curried function?

Comment: `charOrdAFactoryBase` is being redeclared. What you want to export is a name referencing an already defined function. `export { charOrdAFactoryBase }`

Comment: make it an answer @OluwafemiSule

Comment: Done. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`charOrdAFactoryBase` is being redeclared.

What you want to export here is a name referencing an already defined function.

```
export { charOrdAFactoryBase }
```

### Reference:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export